# Alarm not firing

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting alarms but for some reason they are no longer firing (i.e. the AlarmReceiver class is not being invoked).

The code I'm using to set the alarm is:

```
public class SetMealTimersActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT = 134217728;
    PendingIntent pi, mealPI;
    AlarmManager am;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_meal_timers);
        am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

        // Get current date
        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());// set the current
                                                            // time and date for
                                                            // this calendar

        // Set date for alarm from current date
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

        long glbMealId = ((MealTimerApplication) this.getApplication())
                .getMealId();
        // Retrieve meal and store meal_ready_time
        meal meal = new TableControllerMeal(this).readSingleRecord(glbMealId);
        String meal_desc = meal.meal_desc;
        int meal_ready_time = meal.meal_ready_time;
        int meal_reminders_flag = meal.meal_reminders_flag;

        // Set alarms for each item in meal plan
        // Retrieve the meal plan for the meal
        List<meal_plan> meal_plan = new TableControllerMealPlan(this)
                .read(glbMealId);

        if (meal_plan.size() > 0) {
            int idx = 0;
            for (meal_plan obj : meal_plan) {

                long id = obj.id;
                String mealItemDesc = obj.meal_plan_item_desc;
                int mealItemStartTime = obj.meal_plan_item_start_time;
                int mealItemDuration = obj.meal_plan_item_duration;

                int startHours = mealItemStartTime / 60;
                int startMinutes = mealItemStartTime % 60;

                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHours);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinutes);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                Intent alarmIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent1.putExtra("meal_item_desc", mealItemDesc);
                alarmIntent1.putExtra("meal_id", glbMealId);
                alarmIntent1.setAction(Long.toString(id)); // Makes intent unique to prevent one notification overwriting another 
                idx++;
                pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, idx, alarmIntent1,
                        FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (Utilities.getAPIVerison()<4.4){
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                } else {
                    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                }

            }
        }
        //Create notification to indicate that Alarms have been set 
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SetMealTimersActivity.this,  0,
                new Intent(SetMealTimersActivity.this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(SetMealTimersActivity.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Meal timer notification")
                .setContentText("Reminders Pending");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setSound(null, 0);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification myNotification = mBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) SetMealTimersActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(111, myNotification);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reminders Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

I've declared the alarm receiver in my AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.AlarmReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

...and here's the AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String mealItem = intent.getStringExtra("meal_item_desc");
        int actionId = Integer.parseInt(intent.getAction());

        //If this is the final notification reminder for this meal then cancel the "Reminders Pending" notification
        String mealReadyNotification = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_ready_notification);
        if (mealItem.contains(mealReadyNotification)) {
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager1 =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                //First cancel the original Quick Timer notification
                mNotificationManager1.cancel(111);
        }

        //Get user preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Boolean vibrate = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_vibrate", false);
        String notifSound = sharedPrefs.getString("notifications_new_message_ringtone", "");

        Toast.makeText(context, "Meal Timer: " + mealItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        //Take the user to the MealItemActivity after selecting the notification
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  actionId,
                    new Intent(context, MealItemActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Meal timer notification")
                .setContentText(mealItem);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setSound(null, 0);
        mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(notifSound));
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(actionId, mBuilder.build());

        // Vibrate the mobile phone if option is set in preferences
        if (vibrate) {
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
                      .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Utilities.getAPIVerison()<4.4 ????

Comment: Consider changing that to `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` or `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19`. Also, could you explain more by *"for some reason they are no longer firing"*? Does it fire the first time? Second time? Have you turned off/restarted the device?

Comment: The alarms were firing in this app until quite recently (I've been working on code elsewhere in the app, so have maybe broken something). At the moment none of the alarms are firing. The am.set command is definitely being executed.

Comment: I've tried closing and restarting the emulator. I've also installed the app on a Galaxy S4 and the alarms aren't firing on that either.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I've just spotted the problem - this line should have been cal.set, rather than cal.add:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```